How can I move commits made to the file from one repository to different repository but with the same file
I have one repository with a library.
I have another repository with a service, which uses library, but does this by embedding this library instead of using it as a dependency.
Today library in service repository is seriously outdated, we want to sync the code and get rid of the first repository and end up with having 2 different builds (for service and library).
I want to retain the commit history and not just have a single commit made by me, so basically I want to merge commits made to one file in the first repository to a second, which has completely different history. Is this poossible? If so, how can I do this?

Consider using git subtree pull.

Do I understand right that your library is a single file?

Try to use patches. Simply put, they are changes serialised as text files.
Let's assume the file you want to retain the history of is ./dir/lib.txt.
In the old repo:

if file doesn't exist in latest commit, checkout last commit where it exists
generate file patches (one patch per each commit with file changes):
git format-patch xxx ./dir/lib.txt  # here, `xxx` is a commit hash

patches will be generated for commits between xxx and the one you checked out

Copy the patches from old repo to new one. Then in new repo:

apply patches (that will create one commit per path):
git am *.patch



